# How does recursion work when inserting nodes in linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I have trouble understanding how these functions work:

Comment: Use a piece of paper and a pencil and/or step through the code with your favorite debugger.

Comment: if you don't understand how general recursion works , the best thing to do is to take a simple example of recursion and do a trace... like with a pen a paper , follow the algorithm . 
On the other hand , func is a function that you give as a parameter to process the data of each nodes. 
Usually it's better to give a function as parameter in the function that search your nodes , rather than hard coding it. 
It allows you some freedom concerning how you want to process your data in your nodes.

Comment: If it helps with understanding, `map` can be written non-recursively as `void map(void (*func)(Node *), Node *head) { while (head != NULL) { func(head); head = head->next; } }`.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the purpose of the map and fold functions (what are their purposes)?

Comment: Both functions iterate over the elements in the list and call a function for each node. `fold` in addition takes a utility pointer that the called function can use for what it needs to, and which is also returned as its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you post the whole code here, instead of just posting a part of it.

In order to understand the insertion of a node in the list, first you should try to understand - What `fold()` function is doing?

The definition of recursive function `fold()`:

```
void *fold(void (*func)(void *, Node *), void *accum, Node *head) {
  if (head == NULL) {
    return accum;
  } else {
    func(accum, head);
    return fold(func, accum, head->next);
  }
}
```

First understand the parameters of `fold()` function:

- `void (*func)(void *, Node *)` : a function pointer which can point to any function which takes two parameter - first is of type `void *` and second is of type `Node *` and returns nothing.
- `void *accum` : `accum` is a pointer to `void` type, aka generic pointer which can be converted to any other pointer type.
- `Node *head` : `head` is a pointer to `Node` type.

Now, let's decode the `fold()` function definition:

```
      if (head == NULL) {
          return accum;
      .....
      .....
```

This is the terminating condition of recursion - When `head` is `NULL` return `accum` (which is a `void` pointer).

If `head` is not `NULL` then

```
  } else {
    func(accum, head);
    .....
    .....
```

call `func(accum, head)`, which means call the function which has been passed to `fold()` as first argument and pass `accum` and `head` as its arguments.

In the `insert()`, calling `fold()` as -

```
fold(tail, &ptr, *head);
```

- `tail()` : a function
- `&ptr` : Address of a pointer to pointer to `Node` type
- `*head` : `head` pointer of list

Now check the `tail()` definition -

```
static void tail(void *accum, Node *node) {
  *(Node ***)accum = &(node->next);
}
```

Since, first argument `accum` is `void` pointer to which `&ptr` is passed and we know that `ptr` contain the address of `Node **` type. So we can cast the `accum` with `(Node ***)` and dereferencing it will give of `Node **` pointer. The type of `node->next` is `struct node *` and `Node` is alias of `struct node` which means `node->next` is of type `Node *` and its address is of type `Node **`. So, we can assign `&(node->next)` to `accum`. After assignment, the `accum` will contains the address of `next` pointer of `node` passed to `tail()`.

After calling `func()`, the `fold()` call itself (recursive call):

```
    return fold(func, accum, head->next);
 }
}
```

Note that now the `accum` contains the address of next pointer of currently processing node of the list and passing `head->next` means the recursive call will process the next node of list and this recursive call assign the address of `next` of node passed to `accum` pointer. With this much of understanding, now I can say, this recursive call will end up assigning the address of `next` of last node of list to `accum`.

When this recursion wind-up and returned to `insert()`, the `ptr` will have the address of `next` of last node of list. After `fold()` call, we have following in `insert()`:

```
*ptr = new;
```

i.e. assigning the `new` node to `next` pointer of last node which means inserting the newly created node to the last of list.

On similar lines, try to decode the `map` function and other part of program.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation; I didn't post the entire code since I thought it would be too long. Pointers are hard for me to grasp since they're harder to visualize (as opposed to math equations in all my engineering courses).